# what is the "offset" parameter in numpy.trace?

Tags: python, numpy, trace

Suppose I have an N*M matrix m, N>M, then what exactly is the trace when I do the following?

```
np.trace(m)

np.trace(m,offset=1)

np.trace(m,offset=-1)
```

In fact, I want to get all the trace values for M*M; namely, `m[0: M,:].trace()`, `m[1: M+1,:].trace()`,...,etc. and I found those values equal to offset = -1, -2, -3. This is really confused me because I thought offset should be 1, 2, 3.

Thanks!

Comment: [The docs are your friend](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html): "Offset of the diagonal from the main diagonal", or if you prefer: since `trace` is the sum of elements `a[i,i+offset]` for all `i`,  offset just shifts the diagonal

Comment: For N*M matrix, what is the main diagonal? I also don't understand the notation `a[i,i+offset]`, suppose `m` is the matrix, then the diagonal should be `m[0,0]` to `m[i,i]`, right? So then, what is `a[i,i+offset]`? Also, why not `a[i+offset, i]`?